# Need advice for designing university database

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

**Introduction**
Currently I'm designing a database structure for my university. I want to store student personal data and staff (non student) data. FYI, the total number of student's records is about 136K, incrementing about 10K each year. On the other hand, staff's records is only about 3K (slow incrementing).

**Problem**
I argued with my friend about three options below:

1. Create **Person** table, **staff** table and **student** table. The last two is inherited from **Person** table.
2. Create **Person_staff** table, **staff** table (inherit from **person_staff**). Then, same goes to student, create **Person_student**, and student table (inherited from **Person_student**).
3. Create **Staff** and **Student** table.

My opinion, option #1 is the best choice. But my friend argued that if we do that (option #1), we will have slow query when we need to retrieve only staff data, because had to join with **Person** table which is filled with student records (significantly larger than staff records).

Any advice for me? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: FYI, we need to be able to track each person (whether staff or student) who was once a student or staff.

Comment: It might be slower but still fast enough. 136K isn't that much for an indexed join. On the other side, when you have to query over all persons using #2 or #3, you will need a UNION query, which can lead to more significant performance issues. Or you will write a lot of duplicated code. Also you will need to deal with redundant data, wehen a student may also be a stuff member.

Comment: I suspect that querying over all persons will be rare. I'd go with option 3

Comment: @Strawberry but if we do that, it will ended by having duplicated column over two tables? Is that all right?

Comment: Thanks sir @PaulSpiegel, your last sentence is my goal. We don't want redundant data.

Comment: I really wouldn't obsess about it. Go with what feels right, and fix it later if you have to. From an RBMS perspective, this is a tiny dataset

Comment: There is nothing wrong with duplicated columns (only duplicated fields, and.even them denormalization is often useful). The only reason to use #1 is if you have staff that are also students, that person would have a foreign key in both tables.

Comment: If your staff is a completely different set of People than your students then option 3, is definitely ideal, but if one Person can be both, option 1 is more normalized.

Comment: You won't have any issues with those joins either way

Comment: I'd boil it down to 1 and 3 are both fine, but 1 is overly complex for no reason if a Person can't be both Staff and a Student.

Comment: Thanks @Paulpro...our staff sometimes (actually many of them) were a student in our university. Sometimes, after a while, our staff go to continue their education in our university (again). So, with option 1 I think we would have a nice historical data that connecting between staff and student. Bottom note, staff is NOT completely different with student, there's a 'slice' between them, as I mentioned in the last sentence of my question.

Comment: @Putra Yeah, I would go with #1 then. You won't have any slow queries.